# Node can't import npm installed module

Tags: node.js, npm

Ok, it's the first time something like this happens to me with `npm`:

I've installed `node-uuid` locally: `npm install --save node-uuid`

But when I try to import it I get an error:

```
> require('node-uuid')
Error: Cannot find module 'node-uuid'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:281:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:294:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:83:20)
```

But if I import the module manually it works:

```
> require('./node_modules/node-uuid')
{ [Function: v4]
  v1: [Function: v1],
  v4: [Circular],
...
```

Both commands were executed on the same Node.js shell so they are on the same folder.

How can it be possible? any suggestion?

Complete output:

```
amatiasq:~/repos/test$ ls node_modules/
node-uuid
amatiasq:~/repos/test$ node
> require('./node_modules/node-uuid')
{ [Function: v4]
  v1: [Function: v1],
  v4: [Circular],
  parse: [Function: parse],
  unparse: [Function: unparse],
  BufferClass:
  { [Function: Buffer]
    poolSize: 8192,
    isBuffer: [Function: isBuffer],
    compare: [Function: compare],
    isEncoding: [Function],
    concat: [Function],
    byteLength: [Function: byteLength] },
  _rng: [Function],
  _mathRNG: undefined,
  _nodeRNG: [Function],
  _whatwgRNG: undefined }
> require('node-uuid')
Error: Cannot find module 'node-uuid'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:281:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:294:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:83:20)
>
```

Comment: Could not replicate here on `4.4`, what node version are you using?

Comment: Is `package.json` healthy?

Comment: @FelipeSabino Node: v5.2.0 & NPM: 3.3.12

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani package.json looks fine, I removed the other modules from `node_modules` trying to isolate the problem: https://gist.github.com/amatiasq/cc673ed44da8056b7a11383152a48b69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an [issue on REPL for node 5.2.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4257) that was [fixed on 5.3.0](https://github.com/scovetta/node/commit/c74c53a0884bfca918f92e95b922d1f2c40a18ff).

Based on that, the obvious suggestion would be to upgrade to 5.3, with proper care and attention to all [notable changes](https://github.com/scovetta/node/commit/c74c53a0884bfca918f92e95b922d1f2c40a18ff).